# Re-subscribe to an Angular request

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a parent component that is a form, which when I add a user should show it on the right of the screen in a sidebar that is a child component. The problem is that when I insert in the database, it does not update the list of users. It only gets updated when I reload the page.
So I'm trying to rerun the http request to get the users back but I doesn't refresh the view of the child.

This is my HTML of the parent component:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
   ........ 
  <button (click)="OnSubmit()" >Add User</button>
  </form>
  <app-sidebar [users]="users"></app-sidebar>
```

This is my TS where there is the onSubmit function where I add the users:

```
users = [];
constructor(private userService:UserService) { }
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.getUsers();
}

getUsers(){
this.userService.getUsers().subscribe(
    (resp: any) => this.users = resp,
    error => console.log(error)
  )}
OnSubmit() {
 this.userService.createUser(this.data).subscribe(
    () => this.getUsers(),
    (error) => console.log(error)
 );
```

And this is the HTML of my child component

```
<nav id="sidebar">
        <div class="sidebar-header">
            <h3>Usre</h3>
        </div>
        <ul *ngFor="let user of users">
            <li>ID {{user.id}}</li>
            <li>Name: {{user.name}}</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

And this is the TS

```
export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit {
 @Input() users;
 constructor() { }
 ngOnInit(): void {
   }
}
```

Here I also leave the service that I do to obtain the users

```
getUsers(){
    return this.http.get(`localhost:8000/users`);
  }
```

Comment: could you make a stackblitz of it please not sure to understand what you are trying to achieve here. adding a user could be made with a post request and a push inside the user array if request is successful

Comment: That `getUsers` is only ever called once (the subscribe will not retrigger it in your setup). The subscribe in the ngonInit is there to cause the getUsers the execute, that in it self is one shot though.

Comment: In onSubmit instead of calling a new GET request you should use `this.user = {...this.user, ...res }` where the res is the response of your POST request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like after adding an user you are not sending updated list of users to child component. You can create `@Input()` property in child component and send data from the parent component:

child.component.ts:

```
export class ChildComponent {
  //@Input() count: number;

  _count: number = 0;

  @Input()
  set count(count: number) {
    this._count = count;
    console.log(count);
  }
}
```

parent.html:

```
<app-child [count]="counter"></app-child>
```

parent.ts:

```
export class ParentComponent {
  title = 'Component Interaction';
  counter = 5;

  increment() {
    this.counter++;
  }

  decrement() {
    this.counter--;
  }
}
```

[The full stackblitz example can be seen here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/pass-data-to-child-component-31hutt?file=app%2Fparent.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

myUserService.service.ts

```
...

users:User[] = [];

...
getUsers(){
 return (this.users)
}

addUser(user:User){
  this.users.push(user)
}
...
```

submission

```
onSubmit(){
   //POST request is here
   this.userService.createUser(this.data).subscribe(
      (resp) => {
        //if POST request i susccesfull then add a user to you global users variable
        if (resp.status === 'success')
           myUserService.addUser(resp.user)
        console.log(resp)
      },
      (error) => console.log(error)
   );
}
```

child Component HTML

```
<nav id="sidebar">
  <div class="sidebar-header">
    <h3>Usre</h3>
  </div>
  <ul *ngFor="let user of users">
    <li>ID {{user.id}}</li>
    <li>Name: {{user.name}}</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

child Component.ts

```
...

users:User[]

constructor(private myUserService:myUserService){
  this.users = myUserService.getUsers()
}

...
```

please tell me if that's not clear